# React js text don't fit in the screen

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on a reactJS web app .  I get a value from the server , and i want to display it inside a grid item , but the problem is that the value is a long text,the value in my code is `{signature}` , and when it is displayed it does not fit the screen .
This is my try

```
  <Paper className={classes.paper}>
 <Grid container spacing={3} wrap="wrap">  
  <Grid  item xs  > 
              Your Signature:        
              <div style={{ flexWrap:'wrap' }}>
              {signature}
              </div>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </Paper>
        <Copyright />
```

This is a screenshot of the result :
[image]

Comment: Would you be able to provide a screenshot of how this looks?

Comment: In your style object, try to add the text overflow property: `flexWrap:'wrap', textOverflow: 'ellipsis'`.

Comment: @Mr. Robot it doesn't solve the problem

Comment: Try adding `overflow: hidden`

Comment: As it's one long string; you could try the 'word-wrap' css property with 'break-word' value in conjuction with a width value for the container.  word-wrap:break-word

Comment: can you plz explain more or provide a code example

Comment: @louaybaccary; please see below

Comment: Please use <div style={{ whiteSpace: 'normal' }>. Something is overriding default behavior of div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple css issue. You can try this.

```
<div style={{ maxWidth: '100%', overflow: 'hidden', wordBreak: 'break-all' }}>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap a long string with no spaces by using `word-wrap` css property with `break-word` value. Below is an example using HTML with CSS.

For React style; adapt the below css property to use camel case.

```css
.wrap{
  width: 200px;
   word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  oisphfpashdfpiahusdfpiuhapsiduhfpiuasdhfpiuahsdfpihaspiduhfpiasdhfpiuhasdpifuhapisduhfpiahsdfpihaspdifhpiausdhfpisdahfpihdspiuh
</div>
```